# I have an issue accessing a certian page

Tags: http-status-code-403

Google page shows a 403 error, though, If I use the search bar to search anything, the google result page working just fine, I've try to clean the chace, clear the DNS records on my PC, but still encounter the same issue, why is that.

why this is happening on a deep level.